# Actionscript 3 code to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, flash

I have this code in Actionscript 3, but have to write it in Javascript:

```
pressButton.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, press_button);  

function press_button (event:MouseEvent) :void 
{ 
       gotoAndPlay(2); 
}
```

I need for Createjs.

Thanks

Comment: This site isn't about people writing/rewriting your code in another language, at least provide your own attempt first

Comment: Also JavaScript doesn't have the concept of 'frames' built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 things:

1. JS does not support typing (ex. event:MouseEvent)
2. EaselJS does not include event constants (ex. MouseEvent.CLICK)
3. you need to use explicit scoping in JS

So, you could rewrite it to this, using "bind" to establish your callback scope:

```
pressButton.addEventListener("click", press_button.bind(this));
function press_button(event) {
  this.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

Or, you could take advantage of the "on" shortcut in EaselJS v0.7.0 to handle scoping:

```
pressButton.on("click", press_button, this);
function press_button(event) {
  this.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

Comment: Still struggling! and more confused, maybe I didn't explain but the "pressButton is the name of the instance on the stage in Flash & "press_button" is the name of the function.